# Is there a name for this construction from two representations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, tensor-products

I've come across the following elementary construction in representation theory.  Does anyone know if this has a name?

Let $G$ be a group and let $V$ and $W$ be two representations.  The tensor product $V\otimes W$ of course has the structure of a $G$-representation by

$$
g\cdot(v\otimes w) = (g\cdot v) \otimes (g\cdot w),
$$
but this is *not* what I am interested in.  Instead, $V\otimes W$
can be viewed as a representation of $G\times G$, and let $V\overline{\otimes} W$ denote the quotient of $V\otimes W$ by the relations $gm\otimes n = m\otimes gn$; i.e., we identify the $G$-action on the $V$ factor with the $G$-action on the $W$ factor.  We then view this quotient as a $G$-representation by $g\cdot (v\otimes w) = (g\cdot v)\otimes w$.

Is there a name for this representation $V\overline{\otimes} W$?

Comment: I can't post a comment so I will post it here. I think you should be careful with the definition of your relations because they are not $G$ invariant. They are if the group is abelian and in that case your construction is just the standard tensor product $V\otimes_G W$

Comment: Indeed, is your $G$ abelian? If not I'm pretty sure the closest thing is the vector space (not $G$-rep) $V \otimes_{k[G]} W$. Or maybe you'd prefer $Hom_G(V^*,W)$ (assuming $V$ finite-dimensional). Either way you have to convert a left $G$-rep to a right $G$-rep, but of course there's a natural way to do that. (And if $G$ is abelian, a second such.)

Comment: Thanks guys - I was being silly.  In the particular situation I was looking at, $G$ is indeed abelian and $V\otimes_G W$ is what I have.